# Python: reallocate weights with a cap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normalization, clip

How can I reallocate the weights of a normalized dataframe and impose a cap.

For example, if I have the following row of data:

```
0.1 0.3 0.5 0.1
```

and I do not want any weight greater than 0.4. How can I clip the 0.5 weight and redistribute the weight such that I maximize each entry. So I would get:

```
0.1 0.4 0.4 0.1
```

So, the 0.5 was clipped to 0.4, and the remaining 0.1 was added to 0.3 to get 0.4.
Note how in both cases, the entries sum to 1 (normalized).

Can this be done pythonically? i.e. Without having loops.

Ideally I want this to applied to a dataframe such as this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5003, 54.06, 53.654, 55.2], 'b': [np.nan, 54.1121, 53.98, 55.12], 'c': [np.nan, 2, 53.322, 54.99],
               'd': [np.nan, 53.1, 53.212, 55.002], 'e': [np.nan, 53, 53.2, 55.021], 'f': [np.nan, 53.11, 53.120, 55.3]})
N = 5 # 1/np.sqrt(N) = 0.447214
df = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
df:
        a           b            c          d           e           f
    0   1.000000    NaN          NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN
    1   0.200681    0.200875    0.007424    0.197118    0.196747    0.197155
    2   0.167413    0.168431    0.166378    0.166034    0.165997    0.165747
    3   0.166952    0.166711    0.166317    0.166354    0.166411    0.167255
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how to answer the question, but I would like to understand the question parameters better. In your example why is the 0.1 allocated to the second entry? How should that be decided in the more general case of larger arrays?

Comment: It should be allocated in descending order such that you maximize each entry. Another example would be, if we have this row:
0.01 0.5 0.45 0.04
Then the 0.5 would be clipped to 0.4 and the 0.45 would be clipped to 0.4 and the remaining 0.15 would we allocated as follows:
0.15 to the 0.04 (since it is the next largest number) and we would get:
0.01 0.4 0.4 0.19

Answer (score 0):

This works when I play around with it, but I'd definitely be interested to know if you find out that it is broken. The general idea is to melt to be a long-form dataframe to allow for groupby operations to avoid explicit loops

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Df from your example
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5003, 54.06, 53.654, 55.2], 'b': [np.nan, 54.1121, 53.98, 55.12], 'c': [np.nan, 2, 53.322, 54.99],
               'd': [np.nan, 53.1, 53.212, 55.002], 'e': [np.nan, 53, 53.2, 55.021], 'f': [np.nan, 53.11, 53.120, 55.3]})

df = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).fillna(0) #assume the nulls should be zeros so we can add to them

nrows,ncols = df.shape
min_cap = 1/ncols #note that the cap has to be at the very least larger than this value for rows to sum to 1

cap = 0.2 #just using 0.2 as an example

#convert to long form to allow for groupbys
long_df = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars=['index']).set_index(['index','variable'])['value']

#calculate excess per row and cap the overfilled entries
excess = long_df[long_df.ge(cap)].sub(cap).groupby('index').sum()
long_df[long_df.ge(cap)] = cap

#fill underfilled entries than can be completely filled
fill_space = cap-long_df
cumsum_fill = fill_space.sort_values().groupby('index').cumsum()
full_fill = excess.ge(cumsum_fill)
long_df[full_fill] = cap

#add remaining fill to largest elements of each row
final_excess = excess-cumsum_fill[full_fill].groupby('index').max()
ind_last_excess = long_df[long_df.lt(cap)].groupby('index').idxmax()
long_df[ind_last_excess] += final_excess

#pivot back to the same df shape as original
res_df = long_df.reset_index().pivot_table(values='value',index='index',columns='variable').fillna(0)
print(res_df)
```

Output:

```
variable         a         b         c         d         e         f
index                                                               
0         0.200000  0.200000  0.000000  0.200000  0.200000  0.200000
1         0.200000  0.200000  0.007424  0.197118  0.196747  0.198711
2         0.167413  0.000000  0.166378  0.166034  0.165997  0.165747
3         0.166952  0.166711  0.166317  0.166354  0.166411  0.000000
```

Comment: How can this be done for a dataframe rather than arrays? I was trying to edit the existing code but didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: can you edit your question and post what the head of your df looks like?

Comment: I've provided a new answer

Comment: It worked perfectly. But in the first row, why is the entry of column c, zero? Since the entries for b, c, d, e, f are the same (NaN) I would have expected the weighting to be equally distributed among all of them. Is there an explanation for that and any way to to make it such that if entries are equal, then the clipped weighting would be distributed equally among them?

Comment: Also, in my original df, not all rows are summing to 1. I'm not sure why that is. Is there a way to set a condition such that all rows must sum to 1?

Comment: Alright, for small n, I don't get 1 as a total weight. However, as I increase n, the sum of weights equals 1. I'm not sure why that must be the case.

Comment: I didn't know you wanted the weight spread evenly in the case of ties. currently it just arbitrarily breaks the ties to fill up bins. Regarding the not summing to 1, I think what is happening is if you set a cap of say 0.1 for a table with 6 columns, then the max row sum will be 0.6 (is this not what you want to happen?)

Comment: Apologies for the lack of explanation. But yes, ideally, every row should sum to 1 (as each row is normalized to 1). I know it is impossible to sum to 1 for a small N and small cap. But in the case of ties, I want the weights spread equally. Thank you for the update

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to add the new logic for the ties. I think the approach will include a new groupby to group the ties together and iterate through those. good luck!